# Prove that exist a matrix $A_{m\times n}$ such that $T(X)=AX$ for any $X\in F^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have to prove this:

> Let be $F$ a field and $T$ a linear operator from $F^{n}$ to $F^{m}$.
> Prove that there exists a matrix $A_{m\times n}(F)$ such that $T(X)=AX$, for
> any $X\in F^{n}$

**My attempt:**

Let be $\mathfrak{B}_{n}=\left \{ e_{1}, \cdots , e_{n} \right \}$ an ordered basis of $F^{n}$, and let be $\mathfrak{B}_{m}=\left \{ e_{1}, \cdots , e_{m} \right \}$  an ordered basis of $F^{m}$.

Any $X\in F^{n}$, can be written as a linear combinations of the vectos of the basis $\mathfrak{B}_{n}$. That is $X=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}e_{i}$ for some $\lambda_{i}\in F$.

Any $Y\in F^{m}$, can be written as a linear combinations of the vectos of the basis $\mathfrak{B}_{m}$. That is $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\gamma_{i}e_{i}$ for some $\gamma_{i}\in F$.

So, we have this:

\begin{align}
T(X)&=T\left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}e_{i} \right )\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}T(e_{i})\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}\sum_{j=1}^{m} \gamma_{j}e_{j}\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m}\lambda_{i} \gamma_{j}e_{j}
\end{align}

But I'm stocked here, I'm not sure how to continue. What I want is to show that in that last double sum, is hidden a matrix $A_{m\times n}$.

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(e_1,...,e_n)$ a basis of $F^n$ and $(f_1,...,f_m)$ a basis of $F^m$. Write $T(e_i)=\sum a_{ij}f_j$.

Let $x\in F^n, x=\sum_i x_ie_i$ implies that $T(x)=T(\sum_i x_ie_i)=\sum x_iT(e_i)=\sum_i x_i\sum_j a_{ij}f_j =\sum_j\sum_i a_{ij}x_if_j$. This implies that the coordinates of $T(x)$ in the basis $(f_1,...,f_m)$ are the line of $AX$ where $A$ where $A$ is the matrix whose $i$-column is $a_{i1},...,a_{im}$ and $X$ the coordinates of $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much. One question, would it be correct if instead of $f_j$, I use $e_{j}$? I mean, to use this ordered basis $(e_1, \cdots, e_{m})$ for $F^{m}$

Comment: I want to avoid confusion, it is for this reason, I write the basis of $F^m$, $(f_1,...,f_m)$.